# Is MySQL CONCAT with PDO enough to protect LIKEs from SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I'm developing a user-facing, public-accessible website where the user can input an arbitrary, hostile search term. After that, the app must do something conceptually like this against a MySQL db

> SELECT fields FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE %user_input%

I must make this happen in a sql-injection safe way. So my first thought is using PDO as I'm doing everywhere else:

> SELECT fields FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE :user_input_placeholder
>
> $arrParam = array(":user_input_placeholder" => '%' . $user_input .
> '%')

But this string concatenation doesn't feel safe at all to me: if the user provides 'user_%_input' that percent won't be escaped and will be parsed as a SQL special char. This smells dangerous already.

[Someone over at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement) seems to agree and proposes to do this:

> SELECT fields FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE CONCAT('%', :user_input_placeholder, '%')
>
> $arrParam = array(":user_input_placeholder" => $user_input)

This looks better to me, but, still, I'm not 100% sure that this would be sql-injection free. Could you please confirm that this is the correct way to do it? If not, please provide a failing example.

Note: I must remain portable and use PDO function, so mysql_escape_string() is not a solution. I also would prefer not to manually strip-out SQL specials like % or _.

Comment: This would protect nothing: SQL `LIKE` operator will still receive the "%user_%_input" 'hostile' search and process it

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT fields FROM table WHERE LOCATE(:user_input_placeholder, field1) > 0` but I have no idea how fast/slow it would be.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate for `LOCATE(substr, str)` definition

> Returns 0 if `substr` is not found in `str`, or returns the position of the occurence